# Why does Gplmpgdec (GPL MPEG-1/2 DirectShow Decoder Filter) override / detour IsDebuggerPresent?

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, mpeg, detours

In `Mpeg2DecFilter.cpp` the following code is present:

```
#include "detours.h"

DETOUR_TRAMPOLINE(BOOL WINAPI Real_IsDebuggerPresent(), IsDebuggerPresent);
BOOL WINAPI Mine_IsDebuggerPresent()
{
    TRACE(_T("Oops, somebody was trying to be naughty! (called IsDebuggerPresent)\n")); 
    return FALSE;
}
...snip...
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HANDLE hModule, DWORD ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    if(!fDetourInited)
    {
        DetourFunctionWithTrampoline((PBYTE)Real_IsDebuggerPresent, (PBYTE)Mine_IsDebuggerPresent);
        ...snip...
        fDetourInited = true;
    }

    return DllEntryPoint((HINSTANCE)hModule, ul_reason_for_call, 0); // "DllMain" of the dshow baseclasses;
}
```

I can't for the life of me figure out why Gplmpgdec would override `IsDebuggerPresent` to always return `FALSE`. What possible use could this serve?

The thing is, for me it's causing problems due to debugger messages not showing up and (sometimes) the application crashing if a trace message gets written when the Gplmpgdec DLL has been unloaded.

In order to decide how to deal with this problem, I think I really need to know why Gplmpgdec is doing this. Any suggestions regarding a solution are also welcome. I'd rather not have to maintain my own custom Gplmpgdec library though; that kind of maintenance headache I'd rather avoid at all cost. Is there perhaps a way to disable the detour?

Comment: Related: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180604-00/?p=98905

Comment: It is a standard hack to prevent reverse-engineering code that has draconian license terms attached.  Not unusual for mpeg codecs, they have to pay a licensing fee to the MPEG-LA patent pool.  Seeing such code getting moved in the open source domain because nobody wanted to put up with it is standard as well.  Detours has strings attached like that as well btw, free for personal use but requires paying a royalty in commercial use.

Comment: That opens up another can of worms. I'm not worried about the recently expired MPEG patents, but a piece of software claiming to be GPL licenced statically linking to Detours... What are the implications for use of either the DLL or the source code? Should I inform SourceForge? Will they act?

Comment: Oh, and to be clear, you're saying that this code is inherited from before it went GPL? If so, how does overriding IsDebuggerPresent prevent reverse-engineering? Wouldn't a reverse-engineer just use his debugger to intercept the call and pretend it returned whatever he pleases?

Comment: Hans Passant, apparently Detours no longer has strings attached: Microsoft published it under the MIT licence. https://github.com/Microsoft/Detours/blob/master/LICENSE.md Alternatively, I'm considering migrating to LAVFilters since it doesn't seem to hook anything and therefore wouldn't pose the practical problem I'm facing. I haven't had time to test that yet though.

Answer (score 0):

Some DirectShow filters actually don't work (on purpose) when a debugger is present.

I'm not sure if this is a workaround for that by Gplmpgdec or if it is related to the other hooked function; `ChangeDisplaySettingsEx`. You can clearly see references to [Macrovision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TiVo_Corporation#Analog_Copy_Protection_(ACP)) in the code which they probably try to disable.

Media Player Classic/MPC-HC uses the same type of code and it makes more sense in a .exe then in a decoder library.

Comment: Considering that Gplmpgdec is a decoder itself, I cannot imagine this being the explanation. If the author was trying to influence the behaviour of **other** DirectShow filters, why didn't he add a comment to that effect?

Comment: I haven't investigated the `ChangeDisplaySettingsEx` detours. Again, a comment might have been useful there.

Answer (score 0):

I was also surprised to see this code in an open source project.

I think it is just a sort of joke from the developer. If you look the message

> Oops, somebody was trying to be naughty!

for me it's second degree, and maybe the developer had just discovered IsDebuggerPresent, and found it fun to use it...

I also remember that at the time of this codec, some video codecs prevented the debugging of a DirectShow application (using filtergraph). Maybe this developer came from one of these companies...

to deal with this problem, you just have to comment this code, and recompile it.